# How to count records from multiple columns eliminating null values in hive table

Tags: hive, null, sum, hiveql

I'm using the below command to find the sum of records from 8 columns but getting null in the O/P as shown below.

[Command part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFPQY.png)

[command part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQGO8.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM9fm.png)

How can this be fixed?

Comment: I'm getting the output using single record ('H' for example) in the command./

Comment: Please do never post code or data examples as pictures if you really want help and do not want your question down-voted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the thing is `NULL` + something results `NULL`. To solve this, wrap each `sum()` in the `NVL(sum(),0)`, so if some particular sum() is NULL, it is converted to 0 and the whole total will be not null:

```
nvl(sum(case when col1='something' then 1 else 0 end),0)+ ...
```

Or always use `else 0`, like in the first expression (H).

Wrapping with `NVL()` will solve the problem even if column comes from the join and the rows are absent and sum is NULL.